# how to create the object programmatically rather than using the UI library on iPhone?

Tags: iphone, uinavigationbar, uitabbar

I want to ask a question about the objective C on the iPhone. I am writing a program, but I want to create the UI objective programmatically rather than by using the UI elements in the UI library (Xcode). And I am interested in the tab bar and the navigation bar. Can anyone one give me some example code, tutorial website or some link to me? Thank you very much.

Comment: @thyrgle, thank you for your reply. I am interested in the tab bar and  navigation bar. Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Read [Creating a Tab Bar Item Programmatically](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/TabBarControllers/TabBarControllers.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007457-CH102-SW28) and [Creating a Navigation Interface Programmatically](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/WindowsViews/Conceptual/ViewControllerCatalog/Chapters/NavigationControllers.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011313-CH2-SW33).